# Any idea why my Manipulate[ParametricPlot] isn't showing anything

Tags: plotting, manipulate

[[image: Tried it like thisAlso like thisstrong text]

As you can see on the attached screenshots I tried to make it work multiple times, but it shows nothing. Any idea?

Comment: Probably because you're wrapping pathRot in an extra pair of brackets and it also appears to be columnar - it should just be a list {x,y}. But you should show the code where you set up pathRot if the problem persists.

Comment: Also, try `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[Evaluate[pathRot], ...]]`.

Comment: The syntax for the argument of ParametricPlot is [{f},{u,0,1}], but I did try removing the {} around pathRot, didn't help sadly

Comment: Tried with evaluate, no luck still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit arguments for `pathRot`

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

pathRot[r_, R_, c_, ϕ_] := {
   Cos[ϕ] (r + R + r Cos[c ϕ]) + 
    Sin[ϕ] (r + R + r Sin[c ϕ]),
   Cos[ϕ] (1 + Cos[c ϕ] - Sin[ϕ] (1 - Sin[c ϕ]))};

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  pathRot[r, R, c, ϕ], {ϕ, 0, ϕmax},
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &),
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, ϕmax}},
    LegendLabel -> Style[ϕ, 14]],
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Tooltip @@@ 
     Transpose[{Style[#, 14] & /@ {"x", "y"}, pathRot[r, R, c, ϕ]}]),
  AspectRatio -> 1],
 {{ϕmax, 2 Pi}, 2 Pi, 6 Pi, Pi, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 1}, 1, 10, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{R, 1}, 1, 10, 0.05, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{c, 1}, 1, 100, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {ϕmax, r, R, c}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 1):

To see what is wrong, try a simpler example, e.g.:

```
p := a {x, x^2};
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[p, {x, 0, 1}]
 , {a, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Nothing is plotted. The reason is that Manipulate localizes its variables. That means, that the a in p is not the same a as the one inside Manipulate. You can solve this problem, by defining p inside Manipulate, then the a's are the same:

```
Manipulate[
 p := a {x, x^2};
 ParametricPlot[p, {x, 0, 1}]
 , {a, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to insert the function inside of manipulate, but it just still doesn't show. I think my problem is likely that pathRot itself doesn't have input arguments as the variables it's equation variables come from a series of matrix multiplications, where the variables were given when the matrix operations were defined. Could that be the problem?

Comment: If you define pathRot inside the Manipulate it works (at least in MMA version 13.3 ): `Manipulate[
 pathRot = {Cos[ph] (r + R + r Cos[c ph]) + 
    Sin[ph] (r + R + r Sin[c ph]), 
   Cos[ph] (1 + Cos[c ph]) - Sin[ph] (1 - Sin[c ph])};
 ParametricPlot[pathRot, {ph, 0, 6 Pi}]
 , {r, 1, 10}, {R, 1, 10}, {c, 1, 10}]`